# Re: Error (launching minecraft) Java oracle 8

Tags: java, minecraft, oracle

Upon trying to launch Minecraft, I received this error.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
The program 'java' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 587 error_code 143 request_code 139 minor_code 7)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Comment: @Snapper1_cd What command did you use to start minecraft? Has minecraft worked before? What have you changed? What have you tried?

Comment: I just launched the Minecraft exe file from my desktop.  I haven't got Minecraft to open successfully yet.  I haven't modified anything.

Comment: This website is for Ubuntu users, please check out one of the other Stack exchange websites and post your answer there!

Comment: @TrevorClarke I think he was still using Ubuntu, because I don't believe Minecraft.exe on Windows uses `gdk`. Maybe it's through `wine`?

Comment: @TrevorClarke And Windows definitely doesn't use X Window System.

Comment: I am using xfce trusty- xunbuntu.  New user.  Thanks.  I went ahead and removed all and will start again.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an issue with 1.8.0_31, it might be fixed in 1.8.0_60:

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8056151

However this report might be a more exact hit and still reproduces it on 1.8.0_74 amd64:

https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/149

Switching back to java 1.7 helps. Using the workaround provided at http://my.stargazer.at/2015/02/03/java-8-jvm-crash-on-linux/ mentioned by 
Ruud Schmitz (thanks) helps too:

```
java -Dswing.systemlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel -jar minecraft.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Reinstallation does not always help. Create the directory '03@C7:8' in the home directory, and inside this directory create the file 'ync', where you need to write the launch configuration, which is located in the launcher itself (the file manages to be created before the error). I'm use TLauncher and configuration file looks like this:

```
# TLauncher configuration file
# Version 2.69
# Fri Mar 06 23:35:11 MSK 2020
minecraft.versions.release=true
gui.console.width=720
minecraft.versions.modified=true
minecraft.versions.sub.remote=true
client=c561a135-e790-4612-8079-500de0fea2b7
gui.console.height=500
settings.version=3
retest.update=true
gui.settings.servers.recommendation=true
minecraft.versions.sub.old_release=true
minecraft.gamedir=/home/[dir]/.minecraft
minecraft.memory.ram2=4237
gui.statistics.checkbox=false
gui.console.y=30
skin.status.checkbox.state=true
gui.console.x=30
connection=good
gui.notice.ad_other=true
minecraft.size=925;530
gui.notice.ad_server=true
gui.notice.ad_youtube=true
minecraft.fullscreen=false
locale=ru_RU
minecraft.onlaunch=hide
log.file.counter=9
gui.settings.guard.checkbox=true
UPDATER_LAUNCHER=false
chooser.type.account=false
gui.console=none
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Gentoo and re-installing Java 1.8.0 121 b13 *without* JavaFX support resolves the problem.
Perhaps an Ubuntu user can use this information to fix it there.